# Обработчик событий WinAPI в Rad Studio XE5

Tags: c++builder, winapi, radstudio, c++

Использую WinAPI для передачи сообщений между окнами путем посылки WM_COPYDATA. В старых C++ Builder проектах все работает как часы. В RAD нет. Имеется следующий код:

```
class TMainForm
{
...
private:
     void __fastcall OnMyCopyData(TWMCopyData &dat);
     BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
                MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_COPYDATA,TWMCopyData,OnMyCopyData)
     END_MESSAGE_MAP(TComponent);
}

По нажатию кнопки (для примера) посылаю из своего приложения в свое приложение событие :
    void __fastcall TForm1::btnClick(TObject *Sender)
    {
    PCOPYDATASTRUCT pcds = new COPYDATASTRUCT;
                pcds->dwData=1;
                pcds->cbData=16;
                char data[16] = "give_me_data";
                pcds->lpData = data;

     SendMessage(HWND(this->Handle),WM_COPYDATA,(WPARAM)HWND(this->Handle),(LPARAM)(PVOID)pcds);
    }
```

А вот объявленное событие OnMyCopyData(TWMCopyData &dat) при посылке сообщения не вызывается. Помогите разобраться в ситуации.

```
С уважением maxspb
```